# iMac FD 16GB 21.5 inches Retina

Tags: applications, email, time-machine

My old Mac crashed badly and I had to sell it.
Had a Mac TimeMachine Backup.
Bought this new iMac and it came loaded with Sys and a few apps.
I want to get my old email from Time Machine back.
How do I import that and put it into this Mac?

Answer (score 1):

In Finder go to Applications → Utilities, and run Migration Assistant app. It will help you restore your backed up data including email.